# Oracle Field Service Cloud Plugin with Cordova.js

Tags: oracle, cordova

I want to know if its posible to make a plugin for OFSC with cordova integration. I have a web page with a simple HTML plugin, and I want to add SQLite storage into the plugin.

I have tried including the cordova.js reference to the index.html plugin page, and it's loads well, but don't works on the application, When I try to open a database I alwais get an error. 
If I load the plugins files outside OFSC context on a cordova package the SQLite plugin works perfectly.

I am not sure if the it is posible or if it's not necesary to load cordova on the plugin index page because I have seen references to cordova on the OFSC package.js file.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can only use browser cache to enable your application for offline working. You can use browser local storage or browser's IndexedDB etc in your plugin.